# how to match multiple items in perl

Tags: regex, perl

```
my $text ='<span>by <small class="author" itemprop="author">J.K. Rowling</small><span>by <small class="author" itemprop="author">J.K. Rowling</small><span>by <small class="author" itemprop="author">J.K. Rowling</small>'


if ($text =~ m/<span>by <small class="author" itemprop="author">(.+?)<\/small>/ig){
    $author = $1;
    $authorcount{$author} +=1;
}

$authorcounttxt = "authorcount.txt";
open (OUTPUT3, ">$authorcounttxt");
foreach $author (sort { $authorcount{$b} <=> $authorcount{$a} } keys %authorcount){
    print OUTPUT3 ("$author\t\t$authorcount{$author}\n");
}
close (OUTPUT3);
```

The desired output is:

```
J.K. Rowling 3
```

However I am only getting:

```
J.K. Rowling 1
```

Comment: The condition in that `if`, the `$text =~ ...` regex, evaluates to true, the body `{...}` for it runs, where `$author` is set to `$1` and that hash counter incremented by one.  Done.  Why would this happen three times (in order to get `3` which you expect)?

Comment: If you want that `if (...) { ... }` to keep repeating for all matches you need some loop there. Like `while ( $text =~ /same regex/g) { same code }`

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> if ($text =~ m/.../ig){
>      $author = $1;
>      $authorcount{$author} +=1;
> ```

This is an **if** statement which means that the inner block while be entered at most once, i.e. if there is a **first match**. You likely meant to do a **while** statement to enter the inner block for **each match**:

> ```
> while ($text =~ m/.../ig){
>      $author = $1;
>      $authorcount{$author} +=1;
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Replace your `if` with a `while` to iterate through all of the matches of your regex match instead of only the first one:

```
while ($text =~ m/<span>by <small class="author" itemprop="author">(.+?)<\/small>/ig){
  $author = $1;
  $authorcount{$author} += 1;
}
```

Also obligatory note: parsing HTML with regexen is fraught with peril. Consider using a module that can properly parse HTML, [Mojo::DOM](https://docs.mojolicious.org/Mojo/DOM) for example.

Answer (score 1):

As already indicated by previous posters the issue hidden in `if ( $text =~ /.../gi )`, it evaluates to `true` and block executed only once.

You are looking to process **match** in an array context which can be achieved with `for` or `while` loop.

Following code snippet demonstrates one of many approaches to the solution.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my(%authors, $fname, $text, $re);

$fname = 'authorcount.txt';
$text  = '<span>by <small class="author" itemprop="author">J.K. Rowling</small><span>by <small class="author" itemprop="author">J.K. Rowling</small><span>by <small class="author" itemprop="author">J.K. Rowling</small>';
$re    = qr/<span>by <small class="author" itemprop="author">(.*?)<\/small>/;

$authors{$1}++ for $text =~ /$re/gi;

open my $fh, ">", $fname
    or die "Can't open $fname";
    
say $fh "$_ $authors{$_}" for sort keys %authors;

close $fh;
```

NOTE: this code will work for your example `$text = '...'`, if you intend to process complex `HTML` files then [Mojo::DOM](https://docs.mojolicious.org/Mojo/DOM) is a right tool to a problem.